# Class or Interface expected with OnTouchListener android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying to get it so that when I hold down a button it plays recorded audio. And stops playing when I release the button. Whenever I put onTouchListener into my code it says *'class' or 'interface' expected*. How do I fix this?Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button ImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

ImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Start
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // End
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put in in onCreate method.Write the code as:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button ImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Start
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // End
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Remember to write the onclick listners(or any such methods) within the scope of onCreate.